# How to find location of detached log file?

Tags: sql-server

If I have 2 log files on 2 drives for single database , 1 of them is attached ,
IS there any system table/view  which stores info about detached log file?

Comment: As far as SQL Server is concerned, detached files don't exist. It doesn't know or care about them. Since those files aren't used (and logfiles can't be *re*-used, if they're no longer part of the database) you probably don't need to care about them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IS there any system table/view which stores info about detached log
>   file?

Hi Kiran,

It's a good question.
Now about the answer; if you have any existing backup for the database which you have detached; then you can use following query to find the physical locations of your data as well as log files.

```
use master
Go
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'Physical_Path_of_Backup_File\backup_file_Name.bak'
GO
```

**But your database's physical files should not have been moved to another location after the backup has completed.**

> Also in the MSDB system database all backup related information is
>   stored by default. So I have also prepared following query which can
>   be used to find the physical location of your database's data and log
>   file but you must have taken some kind backup before detach operation.

**Script is as follows:**

```
Use MSDB
Go
Select * from backupfile bf where 
EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset ON msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
and msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name ='YourDatabaseName'
where bf.backup_set_id=backup_set_id

)
order by backup_set_id desc
Go
```

**Note:**  :
In the above script just check the details against recent "backup_set_id" to get the proper details.(That will be the top row in the query).

Comment: Thanks Kudan for such a detailed answer.It really appriciated.Since six months I posted this question and finally got a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck due to not being able to find the log location, you might want to consider attaching without it, it should generate a new log file if it was detached cleanly. Back the file up first.